# Caracteres repetidos en una cadena de texto

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, .net-core, net

estoy con un problemita, tengo un ejercicio para realizarlo que consiste en:

Recibo una cadena de texto, por ejemplo: string cadena = "aabbccd";

Debo buscar cuantas veces se repiten caracteres dentro de esa cadena y si la cantidad de repeticiones son iguales en todas las letras o existe un solo caracter que se repite cantidad de veces diferentes a las demas tengo que devolver un true.

Mi código

```
bool resultado = false;
var conteoDeLetras = cadena.GroupBy(x => x)
                     .Select(X => new { letra = X.Key, repeticiones = X.Count() })
                     .OrderByDescending(x => x.repeticiones).ToList();  

if(conteoDeLetras.All(x=>x.repeticiones == conteoDeLetras.FirstOrDefault()?.repeticiones)) {     
   resultado = true; 
}  

return resultado;
```

Si pudieran ayudarme

Comment: Incluye en la pregunta lo que has intentado

Comment: Bueno gracias, eso intente hacer no entiendo mucho publicar esto en la pag. Estoy medio perdido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con esto. En el código están los comentarios de que se hace en cada condición:

```cs
var repeticiones1 = conteoDeLetras.FirstOrDefault()?.repeticiones;
if (
    //Solo hay una letra repetida una vez con cantidad diferente de las otras
    (conteoDeLetras.Select(x => x.repeticiones).Distinct().Count() <= 2 && 
    //Y no hay letras con una sola repeticion
    conteoDeLetras.Count(x => x.repeticiones == 1) == 0) ||
    //Todas las letras tienen la misma cantidad de repeticiones
    conteoDeLetras.All(x => x.repeticiones == repeticiones1))
{
    resultado = true;
}
return resultado;
```

`Pruebas realizadas:`

- "a" -> **True**
- "aabbcc" -> **True**
- "aabbccc" -> **True**
- "aabb1cc" -> **False**
- "aabb1ccc" -> **False**

---

- "hhaakuuuunaaaaa" -> **False**
- "matttaaaataaaaa" -> **False**
- "uuuunnnaaaa" -> **True**
- "fffooormaaa" -> **False**
- "de" -> **True**
- "seerrr" -> **False**
- "heellooo" -> **False**
- "worrrrld" -> **False**
- "aabbccc" -> **True**
- "aaabbc" -> **False**

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero tambien tengo el caso de tener "aabbccc" que deberia devolver true ya que uno de los caracteres se repite 3 veces y los demas 2.
El caso falso que tienes ahi esta bien.

Comment: @CarlosSpertieri he modificado la respuesta para que coincida con la condición del ejercicio.

Comment: esta condicion "aabb1ccc" => True si deberia ser falsa como estaba antes. Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: caso1: "hhaakuuuunaaaaa   matttaaaataaaaa  uuuunnnaaaa fffooormaaa de seerrr"
caso2: "heellooo   worrrrld"
caso3: "aabbccc"
caso4: "aaabbc"

Comment: devolver true si cumple con caracteres repetidos la misma cantidad de veces o solo uno de los caracteres que se repita cantidad de veces diferentes

Comment: Por curiosidad @LeoLopez ¿Cuándo debería devolver false?

Comment: @CarlosSpertieri creo que ahora sí :)

Comment: genial muchas gracias me re ayudaste